# Get specific columns using “only()” function in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables `user` and `post`.

in my posts method I want to return users posts with custom fileds.
none of below solutions dose not works

```
class UserController
{
  public function posts(User $user)
  {
    return $user->only(['username', 'name', 'posts.body' // solution one

    return $user->only(['username', 'name', 'posts'=>function($q){
       $q->select(['body']
   }])// solution two
```

Does anyone have a work around?

Comment: which custom fields you want to return ?

Comment: @JigneshJoisar body field from posts table

Comment: What is your expected output there? Should the return type be `User` or an array?

Comment: @apokryfos return type should be a `User` with custom `Posts` field relation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in post only get one column value in one row then used `value` method

```
Post::where('user_id')->value('body')
```

if you want to get multiple value(rows) from single column  used `pluck` method

```
Post::where('user_id')->pluck('body')    //this will get on the array
```

> otherwise used `select` method

```
Post::select('body')->where('user_id')->get(); // this will get on collection
Post::select('body')->where('user_id')->get()->toArray(); // this will get on array
```